# Yii2: How do I turn a column title of a GridView?

Tags: jquery, css, gridview, yii2, adminlte

I have a table with many columns and I would like to put the boolean columns a bit more together. This is my table:
[image]

And I would like something like this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

The file is an index.php:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>                
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'escolarizado:boolean', // Can I change column direction here?
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{update} {delete}'
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

---

**Update:**
I tried @scaisEdge solution:

[image]

And I tried @Imtiaz solution:

[image]

I would like to have the select component a bit more narrow.

Comment: use gridview template to wrap the titles inside div(s), then use css to transform the div horizontally. `transform: rotate(-90deg)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use  a proper class eg:

```
.vertical-text {
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   transform-origin: left top 0;
}
```

and use the headerOptions for assigne the class to the header

```
      <?= GridView::widget([
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
      'filterModel' => $searchModel,
      'columns' => [
          [
            'attribute'=> 'escolarizado',
            'headerOptions' => ['class'= 'vertical-text'],
          ],

          [
              'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
              'template' => '{update} {delete}'
          ],
      ],
  ]); ?>
```